# How broad can employment contracts be and still be enforcable?

Tags: contract-law, corporate-law

I've seen some very broad terms used in contracts that an employee is required to sign before they start working for a company (or government). For example I've seen a contract saying that the employee agrees to always give their best effort while doing their job. Does this mean that getting caught, for example, checking the weather instead of working, can result in a breach of contract? (Apparently, [they can't get sued](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/5298/when-can-an-employer-sue).)

Comment: What jurisdiction?

Comment: This would be an implied term in every employment contract.

Comment: "best effort" is completely subjective. If I do not check the weather twice a day I get anxious and start to produce sub-par results. Not checking the weather would go against "best effort". So I check it three times just in case. The employer can have a different view and we end up in court discussing something which then is published in Annals Of Court Humor. Seriously - this is not realistically enforceable as it.

Comment: @YviDe Canada and US